# post request with \n-delimited JSON in python

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, python-requests

I'm trying to use the bulk API from Elasticsearch and I see that this can be done using the following request which is special because what is given as a "data" is not a proper JSON, but a JSON that uses \n as delimiters.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "test"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
'
```

My question is how can I perform such request within python? The authors of ElasticSearch suggest to not pretty print the JSON but I'm not sure what it means (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

I know that this is a valid python request

```
import requests
import json

data = json.dumps({"field":"value"})

r = requests.post("localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty", data=data)
```

But what do I do if the JSON is \n-delimited?

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the elasticsearch python client?

Comment: Python bulk helpers are here to help: http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers

Comment: @danielspaniol yes, the reason is that I need a customized elasticsearch python client

Comment: thanks, but this not a question related to the elasticsearch python client, but rather how I can perform such task in python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What this really is is a set of individual JSON documents, joined together with newlines. So you could do something like this:

```
data = [
    { "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } },
    { "field1" : "value1" },
    { "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" }, },
    { "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" }, },
    { "field1" : "value3" },
    { "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "test"} },
    { "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
]

data_to_post = '\n'.join(json.dumps(d) for d in data)
r = requests.post("localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty", data=data_to_post)
```

However, as pointed out in the comments, the Elasticsearch Python client is likely to be more useful.

Comment: thanks! but have you test this locally? I found that you still need to add a comma at the end of each JSON in data or the data format is not valid and also I get the following error `requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty`

Comment: Sorry, yes, the list should have had commas.

Comment: Also, use the `json` parameter in `requests.post` to post json data.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to Daniel's answer above, I had to add an additional `'\n'` to the end of the data_to_post, and add a `{Content-Type: application/x-ndjson}` header to get it work in Elasticsearch 6.3.

```
data_to_post = '\n'.join(json.dumps(d) for d in data) + "\n"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-ndjson"}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty", data=data_to_post, headers=headers)
```

Otherwise, I will receive the error:
`"The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use python ndjson library to do it.
https://pypi.org/project/ndjson/

It contains JSONEncoder and JSONDecoder classes for easy use with other libraries, such as requests:

```
import ndjson
import requests

response = requests.get('https://example.com/api/data')
items = response.json(cls=ndjson.Decoder)
```